# Call methods in objects?

Tags: java

I'm a little bit new to objects in Java and I would appreciate some help. I hope I can explain my situation. I have a class, that I call GUI4EX, to handle the the programs GUI. In this class, I also have the main method that creates an instance of GUI4EX:

```
GUI4EX frame = new GUI4EX();
```

and also an instance of the class CustomHandler, but this is not done inside the main method:

```
CustomHandler customHandler = new CustomHandler();
```

From the code inside GUI4EX I call methods in customHandler like this: CustomHandler.getSomeValue(). How about if I want reach a method in GUI4EX from CustomHandler class? Is this possible and how would I do? Hope my qustions isn't unclear! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand one important thing for object-orientated programming: Methods belong to objects. You only* can call a method when you know an object whose method to call.

In your example, `CustomHandler` has to know the specific `GUI4EX` object to call a method on it. One possibility is to add a parameter to the constructor:

```
class CustomHandler {   
  private GUI4EX frame;

  public CustomHandler(GUI4EX theFrame) {
    frame = theFrame;
  }
}
```

Then you can access the field `frame` for calling a GUI method.

But note that you're going to create a circular relationship. That means that both classes - `CustomHandler` and `GUI4EX` depend on each other. This may cause problems and result in bad code design. If you can, try avoiding such dependencies.

---

* There are also static methods, but they are used less frequently.

Comment: OK! So it's a bad programming to reach methods like this?

Comment: The larger the project is, the more complicate gets the code if you're using many circular relationships. If the two classes are very related and in the same java package, it may be ok. But try avoiding it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your class relationship right for that. If I understand you correctly then:

- GUI4EX has an instance of CustomHandler as a class member
- But CustomHandler is being constructed with default constructor without passing a GUI4EX reference

Though it will not be a very good design but you can pass a reference of GUI4EX to CustomHandler; either in constructor or in a setter method like this:

```
class CustomHandler {
   GUI4EX gui;
   // your rest of class members
   public void setGui(GUI4EX gui) {
      this.gui = gui;
   }
   // your rest of methods
}
```

Then inside some method in class GUI4EX, pass a reference of GUI4EX:

```
customHandler.setGui ( this );
```